# Keep scroll position in ListView when adding new item on top

Tags: flutter

I am using a `ListView.builder` to render a chat.

The scenario is the following: A user types in a new chat message, when that happens i am storing the new message in state and therefore the `itemCount` is increased by one.

If i am at the end of the list, I see the new item directly at the top, everything is OK.

However, if I am in the middle of the chat and an item is added, the view scrolls a little bit. How can I disable this behaviour? I guess it kinda makes sense because the scroll offset is still the same `double` in the `ScrollControllers` state, but if there is one more item, it looks like it scrolls...

Is there a good way to do this? I guess the manual approach would be to measure the height of the new item and manually set the correct ScrollController offset again.. but meeeh

Comment: I think that the "manual approach" is the right approach because you are rebuilding the `ListView`.

Comment: Make an issue for it. This should be a included natively in the lower layer. You shouldn't calculate the size manually

Comment: Does this have any solution for items with dynamic height? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Still need a solution, any news?

Answer (score 3):

In fact, you should not add new chat items to the list. And you have to cache them and then inject the cache into the list after the list has reached the top or bottom. I hope this solution works for you.

Comment: We have to provide a solution on changing the behavior of a ListView, not to suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [flutter_scrollview_observer](https://github.com/LinXunFeng/flutter_scrollview_observer#3chat-observer) lib to implement your desired functionality without invasivity.

We only need three steps to implement the chat session page effect.

- 1、All chat data are displayed at the top of the listView when there is less than one screen of chat data.
- 2、When inserting a chat data

  - If the latest message is close to the bottom of the list, the listView will be pushed up.
  - Otherwise, the listview will be fixed to the current chat location.

Step 1: Initialize the necessary `ListObserverController` and `ChatScrollObserver`.

```dart
/// Initialize ListObserverController
observerController = ListObserverController(controller: scrollController)
  ..cacheJumpIndexOffset = false;

/// Initialize ChatScrollObserver
chatObserver = ChatScrollObserver(observerController)
  ..toRebuildScrollViewCallback = () {
    // Here you can use other way to rebuild the specified listView instead of [setState]
    setState(() {});
  };
```

Step 2: Configure `ListView` as follows and wrap it with `ListViewObserver`.

```dart
Widget _buildListView() {
  Widget resultWidget = ListView.builder(
    physics: ChatObserverClampinScrollPhysics(observer: chatObserver),
    shrinkWrap: chatObserver.isShrinkWrap,
    reverse: true,
    controller: scrollController,
    ...
  );

  resultWidget = ListViewObserver(
    controller: observerController,
    child: resultWidget,
  );
  return resultWidget;
}
```

Step 3: Call the [standby] method of `ChatScrollObserver` before inserting or removing chat data.

```dart
onPressed: () {
  chatObserver.standby();
  setState(() {
    chatModels.insert(0, ChatDataHelper.createChatModel());
  });
},
...
onRemove: () {
  chatObserver.standby(isRemove: true);
  setState(() {
    chatModels.removeAt(index);
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for items with static/constant height (height: 100) added on top of the list.

When I detect that list length has changed I change offset position by hardcoded item height by calling _scrollController.jumpTo(newOffect).

It works well. The list stays at the current position when a new item is added to the top, with no jumps visible.

```
class FeedWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  FeedWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _FeedWidgetState();
}

class _FeedWidgetState extends State<FeedWidget> {
  var _scrollController = ScrollController();
  var _itemsLength = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<FeedItem>>(
      stream: Provider.of<FeedRepository>(context).getAll(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<FeedItem>> items) {
        print('Loaded feed data $items');
        switch (items.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          default:
            final newItemsLength = items.data.length;
            if (_itemsLength != 0 && _itemsLength != newItemsLength) {
              final newItemsCount = newItemsLength - _itemsLength;
              print('New items detected: $newItemsCount');
              final newOffset = _scrollController.offset +
                  100 * newItemsCount; //item height is 100
              print(
                  'Setting new offest ${_scrollController.offset} -> $newOffset');
              _scrollController.jumpTo(newOffset);
            }
            print('Items length new = $newItemsLength old = $_itemsLength}');
            _itemsLength = newItemsLength;
            return Flexible(
                child: ListView(
                    key: PageStorageKey('feed'), //keeps scroll position
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 32),
                    children: items.data
                        .map((element) => FeedItemCard(item: element)) //item height is 100
                        .toList()));
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```