# Flutter - Maintain scroll position when new item added in the list

Tags: list, listview, flutter, scroll, position

I'm building a chat app and my problem is it's not maintaining the scroll position when I added a new item in the chat/list.

[Video Demo](https://streamable.com/zo2w9)

```
Code: https://pastebin.com/58D2BjRc
```

I'm having a problem posting my code here thats why I posted it on pastebin

Comment: Without looking into your code, it's really hard to know the exact issue. Just to be sure, you don't want to scroll your list, correct?

Comment: Here's my code. https://pastebin.com/58D2BjRc

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is an expected behavior. If you know the new item's height then you can jump to new position using scrollController, thus maintaining the position. Not sure if this is possible in your case but you can give it a try. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51844788/keep-scroll-position-in-listview-when-adding-new-item-on-top) for more information. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To keep the scroll position of the ListView.builder when new items are added to the list you can try not to give the `key` attribute of the ListView.builder.